# How to use mvn clean package exec:java -P MainClass as background process in Jenkins job

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I want to run `MainClass.java` using mvn clean `package exec:java -P MainClass`as background job in Jenkins CLI. I want to start jadler server using main class and want to continue running it.

But now it stop Jenkins build to going to be completed. So I want that mvn run as background process and jenkins build status should be done.

Comment: Maybe this post [Spawning+processes+from+build](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Spawning+processes+from+build) helps.

Comment: What's the actual purpose? Can you describe more the use case? Other builds need to use that running server?

Comment: @A.DiMatteo i want to run process in backgroud and show the job staus completed successfully

Comment: @mohitbhunwalia but this background process would then be used by the build itself or by other builds? is something you always need up and running on the Jenkins server? is something coming from a version control system (hence which can change over time)?